# Convert html tag to ClosedXml RichText

Tags: c#, regex, excel, richtext, closedxml

I'm using ClosedXml to export some data in an Excel file.

I'd like to export a string containing some html tags as `<font color='gray'><s>....</s></font>` translating it in RichText color gray and striked.

Code to do it is the following:

```
cell.RichText.Substring(index, length).SetFontColor(XLColor.Gray).SetStrikethrough();
```

or i can use also:

```
cell.RichText.AddText("foo")
```

The problem is that i need to remove also the html tag.

My code:

```
string pattern = @"<font color='gray'><s>(\d+)<\/s><\/font>";

foreach (IXLCell cell in ws.Columns("A").CellsUsed())
{
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(cell.GetValue<string>(), pattern);
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        foreach (Capture capture in match.Captures)
        {
              cell.RichText.Substring(capture.Index, capture.Length).SetFontColor(XLColor.Gray).SetStrikethrough();
              // only content in hmtl tags
              // cell.RichText.Substring(capture.Index + "<font color='gray'><s>".Length, capture.Length - "</s></font>".Length - "<font color='gray'><s>".Length).SetFontColor(XLColor.Gray).SetStrikethrough();
        }
     }
}
```

It works but it mantains the html tag (striked gray).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in the following way:

```
foreach (IXLCell cell in ws.Columns("A").CellsUsed())
{
    List<Capture> captures = new List<Capture>();
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(cell.GetValue<string>(), pattern);
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        foreach (Capture capture in match.Captures)
        {
            captures.Add(capture);
        }
    }

    cell.Value = cell.GetValue<string>().Replace("<font color='gray'><s>", "").Replace("</s></font>", "");
    int contatore = 0;
    foreach (Capture capture in captures)
    {
        cell.RichText.Substring(capture.Index - contatore, capture.Length - "</s></font>".Length - "<font color='gray'><s>".Length).SetFontColor(XLColor.Gray).SetStrikethrough();
        contatore += "<font color='gray'><s></s></font>".Length;
    }
}
```